# c++ Stopping for loop once reaching array size or eof

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

What I am trying to do is input data into an array and the array can hold up to 200 variables or until it reaches end of file. Will this work or will this keep adding in if the file is more then 200 variables? This is what I have written so far:

Also how would you output this in reverse order without printing the 0s in the elements that didn't get anything assigned to them?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 200;
int tripNumber[SIZE];
double finalTrip[SIZE];
double fuel, waste, misc, discount, final;
double totalFuel, totalWaste, totalMisc, totalDiscount, totalFinal;


int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to NAME's Space Travel Company" << endl;
cout << "Trip No" << "\t" << "Fuel" << "\t" << "Waste" << "\t" << "Misc" << "\t"   << "Discount Fuel" << "\t" << "Final Cost" << endl;

ifstream inp_1("TripInput.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i = !inp_1.eof(); i++)
    {
        inp_1 >> tripNumber[i] >> fuel >> waste >> misc;
        discount = fuel - (fuel * .10);
        final = discount + waste + misc;

        totalFuel += fuel;
        totalWaste += waste;
        totalMisc += misc;
        totalDiscount += discount;
        totalFinal += final;

        cout << setprecision(0) << tripNumber[i];
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "\t " << fuel << "\t " << waste << "\t " << misc << "\t " << discount << "\t\t" << final << endl;

        finalTrip[i] = final;
    }


cout << "Totals" << "\t" << totalFuel << "\t" << totalWaste << "\t " << totalMisc << "\t " << totalDiscount << "\t\t" << totalFinal << endl;

inp_1.close();

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What about `i != inp_1.eof()` instead of `i = !inp_1.eof()`

Comment: @sgmart How about neither?

Comment: i = !inp_1.eof() assigns i to !inp_1.eof() every time through the loop

Comment: `for (int i(0); not inp_1.eof(); ++i)` should suffice -- although I'd rather use a `while` in this case.

Comment: You forgot to add a statement to check the size of vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try controlling your loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    inp_1 >> tripNumber[i] >> fuel >> waste >> misc;
    if (!inp_1)
        break;
    // etc...
}
```

You should check the file status right after the input command, as above. The for loop ensures the array does not overflow.

Comment: I think you mean `i <= SIZE` itn't it?

Comment: @sgmart Yikes! Right. (Actually, just <.)

Comment: should be i < SIZE... as the array starts at 0

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200 && !inp_1.eof(); i++)
{
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Not quite right since the input line may detect eof but the code to deal with the input data is still executed.

Comment: @ooga You're right, my mistake – 'eof' condition may arise during reading, eg. after `fuel` but before `waste`. Testing it in a `for` statement is too early, should be done after read to verify that the whole record was read successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You do not check whether the number of records in the file is greater than SIZE.

Also it is not clear why you defined variables as global. At least fuel, waste, and misc could be local variables of the loop.

In my opinion it would be more correctly to write

```
std::ifstream inp_1( "TripInput.txt" );

int i = 0;
std::string record;
while ( i < SIZE && std::getline( inp_1, record ) )
{
    if ( record.find_first_not_of( " " ) == std::string::npos ) continue;

    int fuel = 0, waste = 0, misc = 0;

    std::istringstream is( record );
    is >> tripNumber[i] >> fuel >> waste >> misc;

    discount = fuel - (fuel * .10);
    final = discount + waste + misc;

    totalFuel += fuel;
    totalWaste += waste;
    totalMisc += misc;
    totalDiscount += discount;
    totalFinal += final;

    std::cout << std::setprecision( 0 ) << tripNumber[i];
    std::cout << std::setprecision( 2 ) << std::fixed << "\t " 
                                        << fuel << "\t " 
                                        << waste << "\t " 
                                        << misc << "\t " 
                                        << discount << "\t\t" 
                                        << final << std::endl;

    finalTrip[i] = final;

    ++i;
}
```